# Whatsapp encryption key location

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, encryption

I have an old phone (Galaxy S3 international unbrandedand) and I would like to decrypt my whatsapp backup files (crypt8, as recent as the latest backup which is always at 4 AM, I think).
I've googled many tutorials but they all seem to be outdated.
Most of them presume that the key file is located in /data/data/com.whatsapp/, however this folder does not exist on my phone.
I've also tried adb backup as root on my linux laptop (adb backup -f whatsapp.ab -noapk com.whatsapp), but when I transform this ab file into a tar and then extract its contents, it's just empty.
I've also tried to locate the com.whatsapp folder (not the user files folder with the actual *.crypt8 files, pictures, etc), but I can't find it anywhere on my phone.

Am I missing something? Are the whatsapp app files somewhere else now? Or has the location of whatsapp changed?

Comment: "*adb backup as root on my linux laptop*",  -- root as on Linux or on Android? If the device is rooted, then there is no need to do adb backup. Just go to the location using some root file explorer and get the file. If it is not rooted, then it doesn't matter whether you  run adb backup from Linux using root privileges or not. As for the empty backup,  WhatsApp has [`android:allowBackup="false"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#allowbackup) in its manifest, so ADB can't backup WhatsApp.

Comment: root on linux, I had some problems using adb without root (sorry for the ambiguity). The backup flag is bad, what options are there now? I assume there is no way to change the manifest file ...